# Python - Read an XML using minidom

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, minidom

I'm new in Python and I have a question.
I'm trying to parse this xml (this XML has several information, this is the first data what I need to read):

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UDSObjectList>
<UDSObject>
<Handle>cr:908715</Handle>
<Attributes>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>ref_num</AttrName>
<AttrValue>497131</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>support_lev.sym</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2004">
<AttrName>open_date</AttrName>
<AttrValue>1516290907</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="58814636">
<AttrName>agt.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2005">
<AttrName>priority</AttrName>
<AttrValue>3</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2009">
<AttrName>tenant.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue>F3CA8B5A2A456742B21EF8F3B5538623</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>tenant.name</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Ripley</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2005">
<AttrName>log_agent</AttrName>
<AttrValue>088966043F4D2944AA90067C52DA454F</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="58826268">
<AttrName>request_by.first_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="58826268">
<AttrName>request_by.first_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>customer.first_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Juan Guillermo</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>customer.last_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Mendoza Montero</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2009">
<AttrName>customer.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue>8C020EBAD32035419D7654CDE510D312</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2001">
<AttrName>category.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue>1121021012</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>category.sym</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Ripley.Sistemas Financieros.Terminal Financiero.Mensaje de 
 Error</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>status.sym</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Suspended</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2009">
<AttrName>group.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue>099621F7BD77C545B65FB65BFE466550</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>group.last_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue>EUS_Zona V Region</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2001">
<AttrName>zreporting_met.id</AttrName>
<AttrValue>7300</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>zreporting_met.sym</AttrName>
<AttrValue>E-Mail</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>assignee.combo_name</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2004">
<AttrName>open_date</AttrName>
<AttrValue>1516290907</AttrValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2004">
<AttrName>close_date</AttrName>
<AttrValue/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute DataType="2002">
<AttrName>description</AttrName>
<AttrValue>Asunto       :Valaparaiso / Terminal Financiero Error
 Nombre Completo    :JUAN MENDOZA MONTERO
 Ubicación  :CCSS VALPARAISO Plaza victoria 1646, VALPARAISO
 País       :Chile
 Telefono   :ANEXO 2541
 Correo     :jmendozam@ripley.cl
 Descripción    :Error Terminal Financiero
 Descartes  :N/A</AttrValue>
 </Attribute>
 <Attribute DataType="2002">
 <AttrName>summary</AttrName>
 <AttrValue>Santiago / Modificación </AttrValue>
 </Attribute>
 </Attributes>
 </UDSObject>
```

but when I read the file with this method:

```
from zeep import Client
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

def select():
resultado = []
sid = _client.service.login("User","password")
objectType = 'cr'
whereClause = "group.last_name LIKE 'EUS_ZONA%' AND open_date > 1517454000 
AND open_date < 
1519786800"
maxRows = -1
attributes = ["ref_num"
      ,"agt.id"
      ,"priority"
      ,"pcat.id"
      ,"tenant.id"
      ,"tenant.name"
      ,"log_agent"
      ,"request_by.first_name"
      ,"request_by.last_name"
      ,"customer.first_name"
      ,"customer.last_name"
      ,"customer.id"
      ,"category.id"
      ,"category.sym"
      ,"status.sym"
      ,"group.id"
      ,"group.last_name"
      ,"zreporting_met.id"
      ,"zreporting_met.sym"
      ,"assignee.combo_name"
      ,"open_date"
      ,"close_date"
      ,"description"
      ,"summary"]
minim = _client.service.doSelect(sid=sid, objectType=objectType, 
whereClause=whereClause, maxRows= maxRows, attributes= attributes)
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(minim)
nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName('AttrValue')
for j in range(len(nodeList)):
    resultado.append(dom.getElementsByTagName('AttrValue')[j].firstChild.wholeText)
    print(resultado[j])

logout = _client.service.logout(sid)
```

This only print the first AttrValue (ref_num value), what I need to do is add every field of the XML file in resultado array, I need help to print every field from the XML file, someone can help me to that?

Comment: `<![CDATA[` - this is how the *xml* starts?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `minidom` here? As the docs explain, it's the least friendly of the XML packages unless you're already an expert in (an obsolete version of) DOM, which I'm guessing you aren't.

Comment: @abarnert can you recommend me another? maybe more easier to use?

Comment: Did you read the docs for [`minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom)? Right at the top, it says "Users who are not already proficient with the DOM should consider using the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module for their XML processing instead."

Comment: There are [other modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/markup.html) built into the stdlib, but ETree is usually the best one if you're learning from scratch. The main alternatives people use in practice are the third-party libraries lxml and BeautifulSoup. (It gets complicated, because BeautifulSoup uses lxml as a parser, and one of lxml's two APIs is a clone of ETree… but all variations are pretty friendly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
You should remove all the server stuff and reduce the size of your sample data.

---

This snippet follows your code and gets all `attribute` elements and then iterates those:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

minim = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<udsobjectlist>
    <udsobject>
        <handle>cr:908715</handle>
        <attributes>
            <attribute datatype="2002">
                <attrname>ref_num</attrname>
                <attrvalue>497131</attrvalue>
            </attribute>
            <attribute datatype="2002">
                <attrname>support_lev.sym</attrname>
                <attrvalue/>
            </attribute>
            <attribute datatype="2004">
                <attrname>open_date</attrname>
                <attrvalue>1516290907</attrvalue>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </udsobject>
</udsobjectlist>
"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(minim)
nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName('attribute')

resultado = []
attributes = ["attrname", "attrvalue"]
for node in nodeList:
    a = []
    for attribute in attributes:
        try:
            a.append( node.getElementsByTagName(attribute)[0].firstChild.wholeText)
        except AttributeError:
            a.append("")
    resultado.append(a)
print(resultado)
```

prints

```
[['ref_num', '497131'], ['support_lev.sym', ''], ['open_date', '1516290907']]
```

---

Even closer to your code:

```
nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName('attrvalue')
for node in nodeList:
    try:
        v = node.firstChild.wholeText
        resultado.append(v)
        print(v)
    except:
        pass
print(resultado)
```

prints

```
497131
1516290907
['497131', '1516290907']
```

---

As suggested in the comments, with ET (although you probably should not access elements by index, but this might get you started):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(minim)

for child in root[0][1]:
    try:
        print(child[0].text)
        print(child[1].text)
    except:
        pass
```

prints

```
ref_num
497131
support_lev.sym
None
open_date
1516290907
```

Comment: @DibuEscobedo The edit you wanted is incorrect, my snippet does not produce that ouput!